# differentiate alphanumeric and alphabetic in php

Tags: php, regex, string

i have two strings in a php i want to make following checks in that

```
1) 4f74adce2a4d2     - contains ***alphanumerics*** 

2) getAllInfo         - contains ***only alphabetic***
```

to check this i wrote a function but whatever value $pk contains among above , results into 
true only , but `i want to differentiate between alphanumeric and alphabetic only`

```
<?php
if (ereg('[A-Za-z^0-9]', $pk)) {
    return true;
} else if (ereg('[A-Za-z0-9]', $pk)) {
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: you can also take a look at this extension: http://php.net/ctype

Comment: also pcre is recommended http://php.net/pcre

Comment: to exapnd on the point @mishu made look more specifically at these ctype functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following two functions to detect whether a variable is alhpanumeric or alphabetic:

```
// Alphabetic
if(ctype_alpha($string)){
    // This is Alphabetic   
}

// Alphanumeric
if(ctype_alnum($string)){
    // This is Alphanumeric 
}
```

Visit this link for the reference guide: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php

Answer (score 2):

If you place a caret (`^`) anywhere inside the group (`[]`) except the very first character it's treated as ordinary char. So, your first regex matches even

```
466^qwe^aa
11123asdasd^aa
aaa^aaa
^^^
```

Which is not intended I think. Just remove the caret and `0-9`, so your first regex is just `[A-Za-z]`. That mean 'match any character **and nothing else**'.

**UPDATE** Also, as [Ben Carey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1046010/ben-carey) pointed out, the same can be achieved using built-in [`ctype`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) extension.

Comment: This is correct, but why use custom functions when there are built-ins?

Comment: @Ben, you probably miss the answer. I'm not using any custom function :)

Comment: You have answered the question correctly, but my only comment would be, you have not advised on an easier option. The above is correct, but the solution could be much easier if he was to use the ctype extension. Do you not agree?

Comment: Oh my apologies. They are really handy functions! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Unicode properties for letters is `\pL` and for numbers `\pN`

```
if (preg_match('/^\pL+$/', $pk) return true;   // alphabetic
if (preg_match('/^[\pL\pN]+$/', $pk) return false;  // alphanumeric
```

Answer (score 0):

For aphanumeric:

```
function isAlphaNumeric($str) {
   return !preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $str);
}
```

For alphabetic only:

```
function isAlpha($str) {
   return !preg_match('/[^a-z]/i', $str);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $str)`? Also, why bother specifiying upper and lower case chars in a group, when we have 'i` specifier?

Comment: i've added the `i` specifier. returning preg_match will work fine (there is a `!` before it so it will return false if it finds a char that is not alpha / alphanumeric).

Comment: yes, but negative group matches have lesser performance compared to positive. So your solution is right, but have smaller performance.